# How i can compare two parameter using dynamic linq

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic

```
using system.Linq.dynamic

public class data
 {
  public int column1{ get; set; }
  public int column2{ get; set; }
  public string column3{ get; set; }
 }
List<data> ListOfdata=new List<data>();
for(i=1:i<10;i++)
 {
  data newdata=new data();
  newdata.column1=i;
  newdata.column2=i+1;
  ListOfdata.Add(newdata)
 }

 condition1="column1!=Null AND column1=column2";

 var filter=ListOfdata.where(condition).Tolist();
```

So here when i pass

condition="column1!=Null AND column1=3" i will get the data filter outoff ListOfdata

but  not able to get filter data with

condition=condition1;

Comment: And what is the problem? What is `data`? You should provide far more details about your input-data, your expected output and what you get instead.

Comment: Have you tried using '&' instead of 'AND' ?

Comment: sorry HimBromBeere for not proving proper detail, please check now, and RobinBennett here No problem with "AND"  but i am not able to compare two column with dynamic query. i can compare column1 with any int. or any string value but not with another variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used your code (with a little adjustment) and it runs:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq; 
using System.Linq.Dynamic;

     static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<data> ListOfdata = new List<data>();
            for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
            {
                data newdata = new data();
                newdata.column1 = i;
                newdata.column2 = i + 1;
                ListOfdata.Add(newdata);
            }

            //below I update the boolean condition, it needs double == for comparison  
            // so column1 == column2-1 will be evaluated correctly
            string condition1 = "column1!=Null AND column1==column2-1";

            //used 'condition1' instead of 'condition'
            var filter = ListOfdata.Where(condition1).ToList();

            // HERE filter.Count() give me 9 !!
        }
    public class data
    {
        public int column1 { get; set; }
        public int column2 { get; set; }
        public string column3 { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Please add some details of what changes were made to resolve the issue

Comment: Sure, I simply made syntactic correction, condition1 in the wrong code contains an assignment (=) not a comparison (==) and then passed the correct variable to the Where clause in the last line.

Answer (score 0):

There is a detailed description for how to create a dynamic query for LINQ:

This Query:
_dbEntities.Customers.Where(cust => cust.CustomerId == 10).FirstOrDefault();

looks like this in a dynamic way:

```
ParameterExpression pe = Expression.Parameter(Customer, "cust");
var _prpToUse = Expression.Property(pe, "CustomerId"); 
var _cnstToUse = Expression.Constant(10); 
var qry = Expression.Equal(_prpToUse, _cnstToUse);
MethodCallExpression whereExpression = Expression.Call(  
      typeof(Queryable),  
      "Where",  
      new Type[] { lst.ElementType },  
      lst.Expression,  
      Expression.Lambda<Func<Customer, bool>>(qry, new 
      ParameterExpression[] { pe }));  
lstData.Provider.CreateQuery<Customer>(whereExpression).FirstOrDefault();
```

Check out: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/b1df45/dynamic-query-using-linq/

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Link-only answers tend to go out of date sometimes. Instead of relying on external sources you should add the relevant information into your answer.